# Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core 2.2.2' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'

Tags: signalr, .net-core

I've installed SignalR.Core and it says the following...

> Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core 2.2.2' was restored using
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework
>   '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible
>   with your project.

Why would a "Core" version of SignalR be incompatible with .net Core?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's not the Core version of SignalR, that's the core package of the "classic" version.

SignalR was rewritten from scrach for .NET Core. The first alpha version was [released on September 2017](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/09/14/announcing-signalr-for-asp-net-core-2-0/) as [Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR/). The latest version is 1.0.0 Alpha 2, released on October.

As the blog post explains, this is a significant redesign. You'll have to experiment with the new SignalR to see how the changes affect your application

You should probably track the [Github repository](https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR) and check this [video](https://vimeo.com/204078084) that explains why SignalR was redesigned

Comment: @IanWarburton check the repo and videos for changes. SignalR was redesigned because there were a lot of complaints about performance. In the meantime, all browsers got web sockets, new formats were introduced. ASP.NET Core itself has a very different architecture. It was easier to start from scratch

Comment: I'm a first-time user.

Comment: You need to check the box "Include Prerelease" before it shows up in the list (in Visual Studio).

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem, I solved installing **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore** before **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity**

PM> Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore -Version 2.2.2

PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity -Version 2.2.0

You can omit -Version to get latest stable version of the Package.